# Compress files using Flash or HTML5/JS or Java before uploading

Tags: flash, html, upload, applet

Using an unobtrusive technology (HTML5, Flash, Java Applet) which runs in the browser, is it possible to handle compressing of files before being uploaded to the server?

I'm building software which will be consumed by a lot of slow connections and by non-computer-savvy users and circumventing an application install would be very beneficial for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flash.utils.ByteArray.compress();` as documented [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#compress%28%29)